# When will "git ls-files -u" show nothing when conflict(s) exists, correctly shown in "git status"?

Tags: git, merge, conflict, rebase

## Background

To help resolve merge/rebase/cherry-pick conflicts I have a script that uses `git ls-files -u` to find the contributing commits (and launch kdiff3 with all of them). I have used this script successfully hundreds of times. Today however during an interactive rebase, I got a conflict for one of the files in one of the commits, and my script failed because `git ls-files -u` produced no output at all. If I ran `git status` the file was listed as `both modified` and `git status --short` gave `UU`. This is the first time I have observed this kind of behaviour. Current git version is 1.8.3.1.

## Question

Under what circumstances will `git ls-files -u` not show anything while there clearly are unmerged files, correctly listed by `git status`?

Comment: Are you able to share the example files or create a demo of the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share any of the code. But the conflict was rather trivial, I'll see if I get time to make up some example code that reproduces it.

Comment: Probably long gone - but can you run `strace -e trace=file git ls-files -u` and see what git is doing before it fails to list the file you think should be shown?